# how to use OpenMP in CodeLite?

Tags: c, compilation, openmp, codelite

I want to use OpenMP in CodeLite, but it doesn't work.
I have already choose -fopenmp in compile setting(actually it's the default setting).
My program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Hello World!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result of this program shows that "#include " doesn't work, and the "#pragma omp parallel" is ignored.

Comment: You need to explain what "doesn't work" means. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the openmp support library is installed, for example, on Linux with gcc, you should install the `libgomp` package, for example if you are on fedora, run `dnf install libgomp`, then try compile again.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to pass -fopenmp to the linker to enable OpenMP features. The following steps should help you achieve that:

1. Right click on the project in the workspace view.
2. Select "Settings" near the bottom of this pop-up menu. Settings...->Linker->Linker Options.
3. Click into the semicolon delimited list to reveal ellipses and click on the ellipses.
4. Click the checkbox for "Enable OpenMP (linkage) [-fopenmp]"
5. Re-compile the code - It should work!